# PHP getting random from array return null sometimes

Tags: php

in one array in php i have only one index and data into that, for example:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "{"pk":"4760991153","username":".....","full_name":".....","is_private":true}"
]
```

in this array i don't know how many data stored into that and when i try to get random index from to access to this index of array i get `null` sometimes, for example:

```
$userPages[]=[
'{"pk":"4760991153","username":".....","full_name":".....","is_private":true}'
];

$data = $userPages[rand(0, count($userPages) - 1)
echo json_decode($data)->pk;
```

or

```
$randomSelectedTag = array_rand($userPages);
$data = $userPages[$randomSelectedTag];
echo json_decode($data)->pk;
```

output:

```
"4760991153",
"4760991153",
"4760991153",
null
"4760991153",
null
```

how can i fix this problem to make sure getting random from the array don't return null?

Comment: Maybe you should create recursive method, that creates random index, checks if isset and returns if it is true. Otherwise it should call itself.

Comment: @niklaz yes, this is one solution of which i think about that

Comment: Also, I think that a random index is not an issue here, but "pk" property. You should check if it exists or not. Object that doesn't have that property, or assigned value, usually returns 'null'

Comment: Always make sure the code you supply in your question actually runs and don't have say missplaced `;` or missing `];` in the code...

Comment: I can not replicate the problem. All versions output the same even if there is a random value in the code which means it is very odd if it's not the same for you. https://3v4l.org/5oKgA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your items have missing keys, don't use `rand(0, count($userPages) - 1)` as it counts how many items are in the array and returns a random 0-n, not the actual key.

So use `array_rand($userPages)`

```
<?php

$userPages=[
    0 => '{"pk":"1","username":".....","full_name":".....","is_private":true}',
    8 => '{"pk":"2","username":".....","full_name":".....","is_private":true}',
    12 => '{"pk":"3","username":".....","full_name":".....","is_private":true}',
    64 => '{"pk":"4","username":".....","full_name":".....","is_private":true}'
];

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $data = $userPages[array_rand($userPages)];
    echo json_decode($data)->pk.PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/JcQea

Or reset the keys, with `array_values()` then your other method would work.

https://3v4l.org/2HWcG